# Resize window to size that greater the display, and capture image from it

Tags: winapi, screen-resolution

There is a program, that displays some animation. I need to capture it, to display it on the high-resolution (2k) projector. The display I have has FullHD (1920x1080) resolution, so the video captured from it will be scaled, and hence decrease quality in 2k projector.

Unfortunately, I can't record it on projector.

I tried to change display resolution via the next code:

```
DEVMODE devmode;
devmode.dmPelsWidth = 2000;
devmode.dmPelsHeight = 900;
devmode.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, 0);
```

But it fails if to set resolution that is higher than display's.

I also tried to resize program window. I found it via `FindWindow`, than resized. Although window was resized, the render area was equal to the display size, and all that was out of it didn't update.

The only idea I have is to run program under virtual machine with resolution I need.

Maybe there is way to resize window and then zoom it down like an image? Physically, it will be small, but by itself it will have high resolution?

What if to try access process memory and try to find bitmap or something like this?

Any ideas?

---

**Update**

I discovered a button, that makes a correct screenshot, even if the part of window is in non-visible area. After clicking, it opens default Windows save as dialog. Obviously, I can make a program that will click on button, set the file name incrementing by 1, and click save button, but I will lost a lot of frames.

Bet, that the bitmap to save is created before the dialog is shown up. Maybe I can somehow grab it. I checked GDI objects count before I press screenshot button and after, and the difference, unfortunately is about 20 elements, perhaps because save dialog window objects also counting.

Answer (score 0):

AMD Graphics cards have a feature called Virtual Super Resolution It allows you to upscale your display to virtual 2k, and even 4k. You capture would be 2k, and downscaled on your 1080p panel. I think NVIDIA also has this feature, although I do not know how this is called.

Comment: Also, 2000x900 is not default the resolution of 2K. For 16:9 aspect ratio the most common pixel size is 2560x1440. The Official movie standard would be 2048x1080 (a little wider). (Unless this is the resolution specified on your projector.

Comment: Can't find anything similar on my pc, I have Intel

Comment: Does VSR allow you to actually capture the high-resolution rendering?

Comment: I think it does. It changes the resolution your PC render your display at. For example if you were to up to to 4k and take a screenshot. It will take a 4k screenshot and not a 1080p one. Also I think in his case upping the resolution will not help, since is projector's vertical pixel count is lower than his monitor's pixel count. So either it will be strecthed or either downscaled I think.

Comment: @isagsadvb I found this post on reddit. It should help you. https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/b02gtu/guide_use_dynamic_super_resolution_downsampling/